# Retrieve a python dictionary key based on a value from a list of values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of people living in different timezones. I need to determine which timezone the person belongs to.

I have created a dictionary:

```
mydict = {'London':['bob1', 'bob2', 'bob3'],'Paris': ['bob4','bob5','bob6','bob7']}
```

I figured out, that I could get a key based on it's value through

```
mydict.keys()[mydict.values().index('bob')]
```

The problem is that the value is stored in the list. Is there a way to get to it?
Maybe you can see a different solution to the problem altogether? I thought about creating a table Timezone |customer1|customer2|customern-1 but it doesn't seem like an elegant solution either.

Comment: What is `bob1`, `bob2` ...?

Comment: `print([k for k, v in mydict.items() if "bob1" in v])` ?

Comment: @BlackThunder, I've forgotten ' ', sorry. These are strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mydict = {'London':['bob1', 'bob2', 'bob3'],'Paris': ['bob4','bob5','bob6','bob7']}

person = 'bob5'

for key,item in mydict.items():
    if person in item:
        print ("Person {} is living in {}".format(person,key))
```

output:

```
Person bob5 is living in Paris
```

Or use `list comprehension`:

```
person = 'bob5'

city = [key for key,item in mydict.items() if person in item]
print ("Person {} is living in {}".format(person,city[0]))
```

output:

```
Person bob5 is living in Paris
```

Comment: @ncica you can `print(f"Person {person} is living in {city[0])}")` ;)

Comment: Yes, I agree but I chose this way ,there are several ways how to format print :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function and make it resusable. You can check *person* with `in` return if found and skip next iterations

```
mydict = {'London':['bob1', 'bob2', 'bob3'],'Paris': ['bob4','bob5','bob6','bob7']}

def getKey(mydict,person):
    for key in mydict.keys():
        if person in mydict[key]:
            return key
print(getKey(mydict,'bob1'))
```